# Linked Server Dangers

Tags: sql-server-2005, linked-list, db2

Is there any danger in creating a linked server?

I want to create a linked server to a DB2 database from SQL Server 2005.  Will the DB2 database be affected by this at all (performance wise) or is this all handled on the SQL Server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no danger in general unless you give dbo permissions to the linked server setup, if all you need is read permissions then set it up with a read account..

The queries that are run through a linked server execute at the linked server, so if your linked server is the DB2 server then the query will execute there......but if you write a poor performing query then the DB2 box could suffer from that query..so be aware of that